# Cannot use a Variable Importance Plot when Using Argument 'Importance = TRUE'

Tags: r, random-forest

When I try to run the following code:

```
reg <- randomForest(max_orders ~ ., data = df[-c(1:3)], ntree = 100, importance = T)
varImpPlot(reg, sort = T)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = "") : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
```

But if I run:

```
reg <- randomForest(max_orders ~ ., data = df[-c(1:3)], ntree = 100)
varImpPlot(reg, sort = T)
```

Everything's fine and dandy!

I'm legitimately about to lose my sanity. I've made the MSE variable importance plots a countless number of times, I don't know what the issue is here. Here's my original regression data (df[-c(1:3]):

[image]

EDIT: R has officially gonna full blown schizophrenic on me:

```
> # Test Variables
> reg <- randomForest(max_orders ~ release_age, data = df[-c(1:3)], ntree = 
100, importance = T)
> varImpPlot(reg, sort = T)
> # Test Variables
> reg <- randomForest(max_orders ~ release_age, data = df[-c(1:3)], ntree = 
100, importance = T)
> varImpPlot(reg, sort = T)
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = "") : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
```

HOW DOES R RUN THE EXACT SAME CODE WORD FOR WORD AND HAVE AN ERROR ONE TIME AND NOT ANOTHER?! Well, I guess I fixed the problem, just kept rerunning the code until a plot finally showed up, still want to know what is reason behind this enigma.

Comment: Are you changing the plotting window in between those calls

Comment: No not at all. I also tried 'old.par <- par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))', doesn't help. Right now I'm just rerunning the code until plots show up. I honestly want to scream right now.

Comment: Have you tried in a fresh R session? Perhaps you've created a shadow version of a built in function or variable. What does `conflicts()` show? You didn't assign anything to `T`, did you? You can try with `TRUE`

Comment: That wasnt the issue, and I did restart R. Maybe because there were only 6 data points?